# Как я могу заемитить событие из директивы, щелкнув за пределами компонента?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Я не могу понять, как испустить событие из директивы

Это мой шаблон, где я пытаюсь вызвать метод:

```
<tooltip v-click-outside="clickEvent" v-on:emitedEvent="clickEvent"></tooltip>
```

Из v-click-outside="clickEvent" я получаю:

```
Property or method "clickEvent" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

Код:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  methods: {
    clickEvent: function () {
      console.log('click')
    }
  },
}
Vue.directive('click-outside', {
  bind: function (el, binding, vnode) {
    el.event = function (event) {
      if (!(el.contains(event.target))) {
          vnode.context.$emit('emitedEvent')
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener('click', el.event)
  },
  unbind: function (el) {
    document.removeEventListener('click', el.event)
  },
})
```

Из v-on:emitedEvent я получаю:

```
Invalid handler for event "emitedEvent": got undefined
```

Comment: Что будет если вместо `vnode.context.$emit` попробуете `vnode.componentInstance.$emit`?

Comment: Да, так правильнее по-идее, в консоли выводит тот компонент на котором висит директива.
Но, все те же ошибки

Comment: Тогда вопрос. Зачем вы пытаетесь передать в директиву `clickEvent`? То есть почему бы просто не написать `<tooltip v-click-outside ...>` (без `="clickEvent"`)? Она внутри описания директивы нигде не используется. И вообще, она вам не нужна, поскольку метод, который будет исполняться когда кликнули мимо элемента вы укажете как коллбэк кастомного event'а, который вы безуспешно (пока) пытаетесь выбросить.

Comment: Я видел, что так тоже делают, даже без v-on:emitedEvent="clickEvent". Может ошибаюсь.
После того как произошел клик вне компонента, я хочу вызвать функцию которая скрыла бы этот компонент.

Comment: Второе. Готов поспорить, что сам `clickEvent` - это метод компонента `tooltip`, а не того компонента, где `<tooltip>` используется. Более того, если `tooltip` - кастомный компонент, то почему его имя не содержит дефиса?

Comment: Ну в вашем конкретном случае это излишне, насколько я себе это вижу. Вам достаточно использовать саму директиву `v-click-outside` без каких-либо параметров. Внутри директивы слушать событие клика не по элементу, а когда оно происходит на компоненте вызывать кастомный ивент.

Comment: Я только что набросал готовое решение, скоро оформлю как ответ.

Comment: Да, clickEvent - это метод компонента tooltip.
Хорошо, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте по-порядку. Насколько я понял, вы пытаетесь реализовать что-то наподобие всплывающих подсказок. А конкретно - их скрытие при клике где угодно, но не на них самих.

Подсказка у вас представлена компонентом `<tooltip>`, что уже является **ошибкой №1**. Название компонента должно *обязательно* содержать дефис и, следовательно, состоять как минимум из двух слов, этим дефисом разделенных. На время представим, что ваш компонент называется `<my-tooltip>` и пойдем дальше.

> Property or method "clickEvent" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.

Очевидно, что метод `clickEvent` не определен. Но исходя из того куска кода, что прикрепили Вы, видно обратное. А из всего этого следует, что определен-то он определен, да определен не там, где надо. В процессе написания этого ответа выяснилось (в комментариях к вопросу), что так оно и есть. Вместо того, чтобы `clickEvent` был методом того компонента, *в котором* `<my-tooltip>` используется, вы сделали его методом самого `<my-tooltip>`, что, собственно, и явилось **ошибкой №2**.

**Ошибка №3** - архитектурная. Не столько ошибка даже, скорее просто излишество - код, который ошибку сам по себе не вызывает, но и смысловой нагрузки никакой не несет. Я говорю о вот этой части

```
<my-tooltip v-click-outside="clickEvent" ...>
```

Конкретно в Вашем случае нет абсолютно никакой необходимости передавать функцию обратного вызова директиве в качестве аргумента. Обычно эта возможность используется для какой-то настройки, передачи каких-то параметров. В вашем же случае можно обойтись без нее.

**4-ой ошибкой** и, я бы сказал, решающей, является то, что вы пытаетесь выбросить событие на `root` элементе приложения. Обращаясь к `vNode.context` вы обращаетесь не к самому компоненту `<my-tooltip>`, а к главному инстансу приложения (скорее всего, не факт на самом деле), который обычно имеет id `app` (или что-то в этом духе). Вместо этого событие должно выбрасываться на том компоненте, на котором оно ловится. Поэтому если у вас написано `<my-tooltip @myEvent="hideMe">`, то и `$emit` должен вызываться именно на инстансе компонента `<my-tooltip>`.

Логичным будет вопрос "а как?". Спасибо Эвану, он предусмотрел возможную необходимость поиска компонента и услужливо добавил объекту `vNode` свойство `componentInstance`. Исходя из вышесказанного выброс события должен выглядеть как `vNode.componentInstance.$emit("myEvent")`.

Все ваши ошибки я исправил и создал для вас [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/541268/). Ниже то же самое (возможно даже когда-нибудь будет с комментариями), но в виде сниппета.

```js
Vue.directive("click-outside", {
  bind(el, binding, vNode) {
    document.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
      if (event.target !== el) {
        vNode.componentInstance.$emit("clickedout");
      }
    });
  }
});

Vue.component("my-tooltip", {
  template: "<div><slot></slot></div>"
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {},
  methods: {
    hide() {
      console.log("Hiding the toooltip...");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <my-tooltip id="tooltip" v-click-outside @clickedout="hide">Click outside!</my-tooltip>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit dolor placeat, exercitationem earum voluptatem labore. Ducimus repellendus incidunt eum at, accusantium dolor, aperiam ea rerum amet inventore numquam vel illum.
</div>
```

**Важно**: обратите внимание, что `@clickedout` здесь нечувствителен к регистру (как и все остальное в HTML, собственно). Поэтому, выбрасывая в своем коде `myEvent` вы на самом деле, согласно договоренностям Vue, должны ловить не `@myEvent`, а `@my-event`, если я правильно помню все их соглашения. Возможно, это даже явилось 5-ой ошибкой, но жирным выделять не буду, поскольку неуверен. Общее правило таково, что имя выбрасываемого события в идеале должно быть написано в одно слово и только маленькими буквами (типа как нативные `mouseout`, `mousedown` и т.п.).

И в конце хотелось бы добавить, что данная логика в целом будет является относительно жизнеспособной только при том условии, что сама подсказка у вас периодически на странице то появляется, то исчезает, но уж никак не находится на ней постоянно. Потому как в этом случае на документе будет постоянно висеть обработчик события, реагирующий на любой клик на этом документе, что уже само по себе является далеко не лучшей практикой.